# Node.js and HTML form input array

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I'm building an image upload tool in Node.js and Express 4x.
On the HTML page, when the user drag and drops an image, it is being uploaded via Ajax to AWS S3 and the server responds back with the url.

Now I want to append all of these urls - one by one - to an input field.

Once the form is posted I want to collect this field as an array.

Here's the input:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/someroute">
    <input type="text" name="photos[]" value="" />
</form>
```

Can I append the urls to the inputs value attribute in below fashion as a csv list? Or what is the preferred syntax for the value attribute?

```
<input type="text" name="photos[]" value="http://example.com/1.jpg,http://example.com/2.jpg,http://example.com/3.jpg">
```

The Express route:

```
app.post('/someroute', function(req, res){
    // req.body.photos should equal an array of urls, but I'm just getting the csv list as the first position of the array
});
```

I have a feeling my construction is not quite right..
Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on your need. As per your question it should suffice your requirement. Is Input read only or editable?

Comment: Whatever you do, the value of an input will always come back as a string, not an array. If you send a comma seperated list, you'll have to split it on the serverside etc.

Comment: As @adeneo states, manipulate the list on the server side. If it is a CSV, then you can split each URL at the leading comma then add it to the text area. For example, for each url in CSVList { add url to field } (Pseudo code..)

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought there was a better - more "correct" way of doing this. I will split the list server side. No big deal.